# Compare columns in two tables and merge values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am given two tables share some column names, and somewhat similar rows. I need a method to compare the row entries and insert the value from one table to the other for the matching rows in one column. An example that describe my problem looks like following:

```
big table                    |small table
-------------------------    |---------------------------
customer |address|           | customer       |address |
------------------------ |   |------------------------------
John     |123 Road       |   |customer John   |123 Road
Jason    |234 Dr         |   |shopper Jack    |645 Pkway
Jack     |Null           |   |customer Jones  |789 Road
Jones    |Null           |
```

The **small table** can be viewed as data source for the **big table**, they contain same column names. I have tried **join** methods, but the method doesn't quite fit. The different naming conventions is causing problems. In this case, `customer` names in the **big table** in contained in the `customer` names in the **small table**. What I would like to achieve in above example is that the address of `shopper Jack` and `customer Jones`in **small table** can be inserted into the address for `Jack` and `Jones` in the **big table**.
I hope my description is clear enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Update...from with position of big table customer is in small table customer.

```
 update big_table bt
     set address = sm.address
   from small_table sm
  where bt.address is null 
    and position(bt.customer in sm.customer) > 0;
```

But be extremely cautious this is not a good practice. Would be much better to split small table customer into 2 columns. You also need to address what happens when both have an address for customer but they are different. And multiple customers with same name.

Comment: The "place" function is what I was looking for. Your code definitely shows the direction how I can achieve my goals. Thank you.

Comment: As I indicated test, test, test to make sure you cover all conditions. You had me going there for a minuet  with "place" - it's "position". Glad it worked for you. If it solved your issue please accept the answer.